# where to find chkdsk disk scan report after system restart in windows 10

Tags: windows, chkdsk

When we run chkdsk at system startup and after completing scanning and fixing system restarts. After restarting where we can find the scan report to check whether any error found in disk or not? I have already checked in event viewer but there is no such report.

Comment: its in the Event Log > Application Logs. the chkdsk output will be printed there verbatim. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/40822-read-chkdsk-log-event-viewer-windows-10-a.html#option1

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: One more questions, How can I shutdown system automatically after scan completion? please answer this.